# Complex conditional filtering in dplyr; dplyr grammar understanding

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

Can I filter dataset with columns `eid, epoch0, epoch1, epoch2, epoch3` where `eid` are integers and `epoch0-3` are booleans, to keep those rows identified by `eid`s which has at least one of `TRUE` over `epoch1-3`? (so it includes rows like `001, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE` and `001, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE` will be selected, but row like `001, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE` only without other rows with `eid == 001` with at least one `TRUE` in epoch `1 - 3` will not be selected). Is this conditional too strange to fit into `dplyr` grammar? Is there a way I can understand the logic of `dplyr` grammar better? I feel like every time I'm running to issues beyond basic coding that's intuitive I can only ask for help here, but I wonder what will be ways I can figure this out myself.

```
df <- data.frame(list(c(001, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),c(001, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE),c(002, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)), col.names=c(eid, epoch0, epoch1, epoch2, epoch3))

df %>% filter(...) 

eid, epoch0, epoch1, epoch2, epoch3
001, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE
001, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example with expected input and output

Comment: @monotonic Could you clarify your question? Are you looking for a code that returns only those rows where the number of "TRUE"s in epoch* columns is equal or larger than the value in the column eid? In your question you first say that "001, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE" should be selected and then you say that the same row should not be selected. Did you mean that the row "002 , TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE" will not be selected?